# How to implement SOCK_SEQPACKET using AF_UNIX family for client and server in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, unix, posix

Does the functionality of `SOCK_SEQPACKET` available in python? Can I have an example on how client and server communicate to each other through this type of socket that utilise `MSG_EOR`?
http://urchin.earth.li/~twic/Sequenced_Packets_Over_Ordinary_TCP.html

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the [socket module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#module-socket) provides a `SOCK_SEQPACKET` constant, so it should work if your OS supports that combination of socket family and type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Shawn. Do you know how to utilise `MSG_EOR` on client and server side as indicated here: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/recv.2.en.html

Comment: In python? I don't know the language, but  I'd start by reading the section on `recvmsg()` in the socket module documentation, which shows how to access the ancillary data it returns.